# Need to find array of array with specific key

Tags: php, arrays

I need to count the times a key/variable is shown inside an array of arrays.

The array looks like this:

```
Array 
{ 
[3] => Array
{
[type]=>group
[name]=>3st group
[newmsgs]=>3
}
[2] => Array
{
[type]=>group
[name]=>2nd group
}
[1] => Array
{
[type]=>group
[name]=>1st group
[newmsgs]=>1
}
}
```

I am looking for a function that runs and returns 2 since there are only 2 arrays that have the 'newmsgs' key with value.

I've tried `array_count_values()` without success, as well as trying a simple `count()` which I knew has a slim chance of working.

Any idea of how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the column you want and count them:

```
$count = count(array_column($array, 'newmsgs'));
```

Comment: Thank you AbraCadaver, this works perfectly too! just had to test and see if this work as it seems a little simpler than u_mulder and it works as well.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not AbraCadaver_da_boss? :-(

Comment: I would say AbraCadaver_da_king :D

Answer (score 1):

Mix of `array_filter` and `sizeof`:

```
echo sizeof(array_filter($array, function($v) { return !empty($v['newmsgs']); } ));
```

`array_filter` will return array of elements where `newmsgs` key is set, and `sizeof` will get size of this returned array.

Comment: u_mulder, you should update your name to u_mulder_da_boss. 
This worked perfectly and is elegant!

Thank you!